# Does it matter which NFC tags I use for my android app?

Tags: android, nfc, android-5.0-lollipop

I am planning to purchase some NFC tags for my Android App which I am developing. The aim of the NFC tags is for the user to tap their phone on the tag which will open the app. I've researched around the web and its possible for open an app from tapping a NFC tag.

My question is does it matter which tag I buy to achieve this goal?
And can you recommend any NFC tags which would be best for this goal?

Thank you

Comment: You can choose any NFC Tag like `Type MIFARE Tag`, `classic Tag`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use **Mifare Ultralight** or **NFC TAG 203** which are compatible with all Android devices.
Don't use Mifare Classic they are not supported by all android devices.

this [link](http://rapidnfc.com/which_nfc_chip) might help you to choose

Comment: Would you recommend either 
http://www.amazon.co.uk/NFC-tags-Writeable-Programmable-Money-Back/dp/B00CE3IC74/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1420551407&sr=8-2&keywords=nfc+tag

or

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Kamor%C2%AE-NFC-Tags-Waterproof-Keychain/dp/B00DRDZ08E/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1420551407&sr=8-7&keywords=nfc+tag

Comment: The first is NTAG 213 which is the continuation of the Ultralight and NTAG203. I Have never tested NTAG 213 but it will work as NTAG 203. The second is NTAG 203 and is OK. You can choose both.

Comment: There is now also 215 and 216 which is continuation with more memory/features. If you need for cheap ask these guys: http://castlestone.io